# Categorical mixture model when mixture components are not PDFs (don't sum to 1)

Tags: probability, modeling, fitting, mixture-distribution

I constructed a model that behaves the way I want, it successfully recovers parameters from simulated data, etc. However, I get the feeling that I re-invented the wheel, so to speak - surely someone has come across this problem before, solved it, there is someone I can cite, some name for the technique, some better way to do it, etc.

I have observations $Y=\{y_{is}\}$, where $s\in\{1,\ldots\,S\}$ indicates a particular site, and $i$ indexes observations within a site $s$. Each $y_{is}$ takes one of $C$ possible labels: $y_{is} \in \{1,\ldots\,C\}$.

The probability that $y_{is}=c$ is influenced by $K$ different categorical predictors, where each $k$ gives a probability distribution for the labels $C$ for each site $s$, i.e. $\theta_{k,s}=(\theta_{k,s,1},\ldots\,\theta_{k,s,C})$ is a probability distribution at site $s$ over the labels $C$. All $\theta$ are known; the only unknown is how likely it is that $y_{is}$ was drawn from $\theta_k$.

At this point, it sounds like a typical mixture distribution, in which $\alpha_k$ is the mixture proportion (i.e., the probability that you draw from $\theta_k$):

$$
P(y_{is}=c\mid\Theta) = \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k\theta_{k,s,c}
$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k=1$$

However, for a mixture distribution to work, each $\theta$ is a PDF, such that $\sum_{c=1}^C\theta_{k,s_i,c}=1$, but in my case $\theta$ is not a real probability distribution, but instead $\sum_{c=1}^C\theta_{k,s_i,c} \in [0,1]$. Since $y_{is}\in C$ but it is possible that $\sum_{c=1}^CP(y_{is}=c\mid\Theta)<1$, this model clearly does not work.

EDIT #2 (updated the model specification, following comments):

The model I have come up with that works as intended is to create a normalized version of $\theta$, $\phi_{k,s,c}=\frac{\theta_{k,s,c}}{\sum_{c=1}^C\theta_{k,s,c}}$, and a new variable $P(k \mid s)=\sum_{c=1}^C\theta_{k,s,c}$. Notice that since $\theta_{k,s,c}=P(k \mid s)\phi_{k,s,c}$ it is now possible to formulate my problem as a sort of mixture model:

$$
P(y_{is}=c\mid\Theta) = \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_{k,s}\phi_{k,s,c}
$$
$$\sum_{c=1}^C\phi_{k,s,c}=1$$
$$
\alpha_{k,s}=\frac{\beta_kP(k \mid s)}{\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_kP(k \mid s)}
$$
$$P(k \mid s) \in [0,1]$$

In this model, all $\phi$ and $P(k \mid s)$ are known, and we seek to find the parameters $(\beta_1,\ldots\,\beta_K$). To fit the model, we can set $\beta_1=1$ and fit the rest of the $\beta$s using MLE or grid search.

What is different about this model, compared to a the multinomial mixture models I've seen before, is that the mixture proportions $\alpha_{k,s}$ come from a combination of a known parameter ($P(k \mid s)$) and an unknown parameter ($\beta_k$). So, really, I seek to fit a hyperparameter on the mixture proportion, rather than the mixture proportion itself.

Does this type of model have a name/literature behind it? Alternatively, can my problem be solved using some other technique (e.g. some sort of Dirichlet-multinomial regression or something...) that is citeable/has been well-characterized/etc.?

EDIT #3: Here is an alternate model, where the model is very typical, but the manner in which I would have to fit it is atypical. As far as I can tell, it yields exactly the same information as the model in EDIT #2.

Let:
$$D \supset C$$
$$D-C=\{other\}$$
$$\phi_{k,s}=\{\theta_{k,s,1},...,\theta_{k,s,C},1-\sum_{c=1}^C\theta_{k,s,c}\}$$

Note that we've constructed a proper PDF $\phi$ by adding a missing category, "other", to $C$. Now let:

$$Z = \{z_{js}\}$$
$$P(z_{js} = d \mid \Theta)=\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k\phi_{k,s,d}$$
$$Y = \{z\mid z \in Z, z \neq other\}$$

Then:
$$P(y_{is} = c \mid \Theta) = \frac{P(z_{js} = c \mid \Theta)}{1-P(z_{js} = other \mid \Theta)}$$

In other words, $Y$ is constructed by making some unknown number of draws from $D$, and removing all the draws with a value of "other"; alternatively each $y$ is a the result of drawing repeatedly from $D$ until you get a value besides "other". In this model, we know each $\phi$ and we know $Y$ (but **not** $Z$), and we want to find the $\alpha$s knowing just this subset of data.

Notice that in the Edit #2 model, there are an infinite number of fits, so long as the ratios of $\beta$s are constant. When those $\beta$s are normalized to sum to 1, then they will be equal to the $\alpha$s in the Edit #3 model.

Here's a toy example with numbers:

Let:
$$C \in \{red,green,blue\}$$
$$K \in \{pencil,pen\}$$
$$S \in \{wall, table\}$$
$$
\theta_{wall,pencil}=[0.2,0.4,0.4],
\theta_{wall,pen}=[0.8,0.1,0.1],$$
$$\theta_{table,pencil}=[0,0,0.1],
\theta_{table,pen}=[0.3,0.3,0.4]
$$

Notice that $\theta_{table,pencil}$ does not sum to 1; imagine that e.g. $\theta_{table,pencil,orange}=0.9$, but $C$ cannot be orange. In my desired model, when the "mixture-like" parameters for $\theta$ are equal to the same value (i.e. when $\beta_{pencil}=\beta_{pen}$), then I want the distribution of $C$ at $wall$ to be [0.5,0.25,0.25], and the distribution of $C$ at $table$ to be [0.2727,0.2727,0.4546]. If $\beta_{pencil}=2\beta_{pen}$, then I want the distribution of $C$ at $wall$ to be [0.4,0.3,0.3], and the distribution of $C$ at $table$ to be [0.25,0.25,0.5].

Using the model in Edit #2, we can e.g. get:

$$P(y_{is}=blue \mid \beta_{pencil}=2/3,\beta_{pen}=1/3)=\frac{(2/3)(0.1)}{(2/3)(0.1)+(1/3)(1)}(1)+\frac{(1/3)(1)}{(2/3)(0.1)+(1/3)(1)}(0.4)=0.5$$

Using the model in Edit #3, we can get the same result:

$$P(y_{is}=blue \mid \alpha_{pencil}=2/3,\alpha_{pen}=1/3)=\frac{(2/3)(0.1)+(1/3)(0.4)}{1-((2/3)(0.9)+(1/3)(0))}=0.5$$

Edit #2 is a non-standard model because it's a mixture model where I'm fitting a hyperparameter on the mixture proportion instead of the mixture proportion itself; it's also weird because multiplying each $\beta$ by the same constant yields an identical model (so there are infinite fits, and you have to either fix the value of one $\beta$ term, or care about the ratio of two $\beta$s.

Edit #3 is a non-standard model because I'm fitting a typical mixture model, but the mixture model generates a superset of the data that I'm fitting it to.

For my application, I think both models are theoretically defensible. And, as far as I can tell, the models are equivalent in that given some data $Y$ they both recover the same parameters (that is, $\beta$ in Edit #2 and $\alpha$ in Edit #3 are the same). However, I don't know whether one model will be easier to fit, or whether e.g. it might be easier to estimate the standard errors on the coefficients of one vs. the other model. Is there a good reason to use the model in Edit #2 vs. Edit #3?

Comment: What is $\alpha$? Is it comprised of exactly K-1 0's and exactly one 1, i.e. to indicate gropu membership? Is it a parameter or data?

Comment: @psboonstra Sorry, added additional information. It is the mixture proportion (so it is K values in [0,1] that sum to 1), and in that model it is the parameter of interest.

Comment: What I find confusing is that you first state that $\theta_{k,s}$ is a probability distribution, and then later you say that the components of $\theta_{k,s}$ don't necessarily sum up to one and therefore it is not a probability distribution. But if the sum of the $\theta_{k,s_i,c}$ is smaller than one, what does this actually mean for the probability of $\{y_{is}=c\}$? Are there possible values other than $1,\ldots,C$? Can it happen that $y_{is}$ is not observed at all? Would it make sense to introduce a category $C+1$ for that case so that you are in a regular mixture situation again?

Comment: @Lewian $y_{is}$ is always observed and is always in C. If we introduced a category $C+1$, this would allow each $\theta_{k,s}$ to sum to 1, but it would still not be a regular mixture:  $y$ will never take that value. E.g., imagine that $C$ are the colors red, green, and blue. $y_{is}$ will only ever be red, green, or blue, but $\theta_{k,s}$ could predict 100% orange for that site. In that scenario, $y_{is}$ is influenced only by the other predictors in $K$.

Comment: @Lewain I added an example with numbers to my original question - maybe that helps?

Comment: What I don't get is what it actually means if the $\theta_{k,s_i,c}$ don't add up to one, and I think this is important for your question. Surely if they don't, they do not define a probability distribution, so you shouldn't state they do. $[0,0,0.1]$ means what? That on the table with pencil you *always* observe "blue"? If this is so, the probabilities are  actually $[0,0,1]$, and you could choose $\theta_{table,pencil}$ like that. If not, why not?

Comment: Note that the term "probability" has a meaning. If these things don't add up to one, either a possible outcome is missing (which is why I had suggested adding a category $C+1$), or they are not probabilities. But if they are not probabilities, you have to explain what else they are in order to make your question clear.

Comment: @Lewain Sure, if we want to make $\theta$ a real probability distribution, we can add $C+1 = "other"$, so $\theta_{table,pencil} = [0,0,0.1,0.9]$. But even if we do that, it is still the case that $y \in \{red,green,blue\}$, so the 0.9 never influences $y$. Does that make sense? When $\beta_{pencil}=\beta_{pen}$, the distribution of $C$ at $table$ should be [0.2727,0.2727,0.4546,0], not [0.15,0.15,0.25,0.45].

Comment: You still haven't explained what it actually means that the $\theta_{k,s_i,c}$ are $[0,0,0.1]$, so I can't tell. If as you say $y\in\{red,green,blue\}$, there must be a probability distribution with probabilities that add to 1, no? Don't you have any idea how the $[0,0,0.1]$ relate to this? And if you don't, how can we? If it means that $y$ is always blue, the probabilities would be $[0,0,1]$, and in general you can get probabilities by dividing the $\theta_{k,s}$-vectors by their sum. But whether this is appropriate depends on the meaning of your parameters, which you haven't told us.

Comment: @Lewain Your last comment (dividing $\theta$ by its sum) made me realize that I could formulate the model using a probability distribution by essentially normalizing $\theta$ and putting $\sum_c\theta$ into the $\alpha$ term. I've now updated my "working model" (see "EDIT #2"), which now more closely approximates a typical multinomial mixture model, and now uses a probability distribution instead of my weird $\theta$ distribution. Does this make it more clear what [0,0,0.1] means, to formulate it as "a 10% chance of drawing from [0,0,1]"?

Comment: I gather you mean "all $P(k|s)$ are known" rather than $P(s|s)$. Other than that, it makes sense to me now. This is a valid model. To make it clearer to a new reader you should probably state from the beginning that the $\alpha$ depend on both $k$ and $s$ and that the dependence on $s$ is expressed indirectly in the $\theta$-vectors in the way you have now explained. However, I believe that this is a highly nonstandard model and I'd be surprised if you found something like this in the literature. I know the mixture literature fairly well, but there are 100s of papers, so who knows for sure?

Comment: what's your model for? also, from what computations the numbers (0.2727, 0.2727, 0.4546) come from?

Comment: I'd actually think if you have a method to fit this, this will secure you a publication, and I'm quite sure you haven't reinvented the wheel there. The only keyword that comes to my mind you could look up is "mixture of experts models", where I have seen something like mixture proportions depending on "intermediate levels" such as your $s$. Can't point at anything specific out of the top of my head though.

Comment: Oh and by the way, your title is misleading because your mixture components are proper pdfs now. It was never the problem really that "mixture components were not pdfs"; rather that you wrote things down in such a way that you and others couldn't see how in fact they are.

Comment: agree. it's quite hard for others to understand where the problem is. i can't.

Comment: @Lewain Actually, I thought of another way to frame the question that gives identical results, but might make more sense to describe (or might remind you of an existing model). Suppose that instead of normalizing, I turn each of my $\theta$ into PDFs by adding a category $C+1=1-\sum\theta$, so e.g. $\theta_{table,pencil}=[red=0, green=0, blue=0.1,other=0.9]$. Suppose I make some unknown number of observations from each $\theta_k$, and I tell you the counts of red, green, and blue (I do not tell you the count of "other") and the values of $\theta$. I want to recover the mixture proportions.

Comment: @carlo re: what is the model for - maybe my answer to Lewain just above this helps? You could think of my problem as fitting a mixture distribution when I don't get to know the counts of one of the outcomes (or the total number of draws).The easiest way to get [0.2727,0.2727,0.4546] is to normalize [0,0,0.1] + [0.3,0.3,0.4] to a probability distribution. If you're following the model, then e.g. let $\beta_1=\beta_2=1$ and then e.g. $P(y=red)=\frac{(1)(0.1)}{(1)(0.1)+(1)(1)}(0)+\frac{(1)(1)}{(1)(0.1)+(1)(1)}(0.3)=0.2727$

Comment: i meant how do you need to apply the model

Comment: Re "Another way to frame the question": If I understand this correctly, this should *not* give identical results, because it describes a different probability mechanism. This could be valid as well but would model a different way to obtain the $y$-data. As you haven't explained the mechanism that leads to your data well enough (I'm with carlo on that one  - you have avoided that question from the beginning) I have no idea whether this is more or less valid for your specific problem than the other one.

Comment: Reason: In "Edit 2", If $P(k|s)$ is small, $\alpha_{ks}$ will most likely be small. If the $\theta$-vector is $[0,0,0.1]$, this means you should expect a rather small mixture proportion  $\alpha_{ks}$. In your new proposal, if the $\theta$-vector is $[0,0,0.1]$, you expect 90% "other" from that mixture component, meaning that the $\alpha_{ks}$ should be much larger than the relative proportion of valid observations from $\{red,green,blue\}$. (The count of "other" can be fairly well guessed in that model even if you don't tell me.)

Comment: @Lewain I don't think the "other" count can be guessed...e.g., if you only know R/G/B counts, then [0,0,1,0] and [0,0,0.1,0.9] should be indistinguishable, right? Also, in the "new proposal" if $P(k \mid s)$ is small that $\alpha_{k,s}$ will be small, but remember that in the "Edit 2" model, we ultimately fit $\beta_{k}$, and I think that $\alpha_{k|"new proposal"}=\frac{\beta_{k|"Edit 2"}}{\sum_K\beta_{k|"Edit 2"}}$, - e.g. in the toy model setting $\alpha_{pencil}=1/3$ and $\alpha_{pen}=2/3$ and using the "new proposal", you get the same answer as setting $\beta_{pencil}=1,\beta_{pen}=2$.

Comment: I added this new model as "EDIT #3" in the post, and I also added calculations using both models for the toy example, showing that they are equivalent (I think). Finally, I added a more formal question that can be answered, since I would like to award the bounty to @Lewian for helping me think through this much better, but cannot award it to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer although it is still some kind of comment.
The way you set up the "Edit 3 model" looks indeed equivalent to the "Edit 2 model"; I had suggested something like the "Edit 2 model" exactly having in mind the probability of observing category X (say) conditionally on only being able to observe the categories that are explicitly given, based on the assumption that probabilities are proportional to the given parameters (i.e., $[0,0,0.1]$ becomes $[0/0.1,0/0.1,0.1/0.1]=[0,0,1]$. (You don't need to introduce an additional "other" category to get there but you can.) I'm not 100% sure because your notation is somewhat strange; in the Edit 3 model you have $\alpha_k$ instead of $\alpha_{k,s}$ and your $Y$ is strictly formally not quite what you say it is; in your formal definition it is a set, but in your writing it is a value. Anyway, I think I get what you mean. But the question whether the Edit 2 or Edit 3 model are preferable is then void, because they are the same. Particularly it is not the case that "Edit #3 is a non-standard model because I'm fitting a typical mixture model, but the mixture model generates a superset of the data that I'm fitting it to" - no! The Edit 3 model is based on ignoring the "other"-category, so it can indeed be ignored, and without it it is the same standard mixture as the Edit 2 model. (What's non-standard about this is not the model itself but rather what information you have and what you don't have, and what you want to estimate - for this, as written before, my only hint, which may not be very good, is to have a look at literature about "mixtures of experts models".)

From a modellers' perspective the question whether this model is fine (I'm identifying the Edit 2 and Edit 3 models now because they're equivalent, so basically the same model written down differently) is the question whether this actually models the process to be modelled appropriately. Is the correct probability interpretation of the parameters $[0,0,0.1]$ that indeed these are probabilities but the remaining 0.9 are eaten by another category that occurs but is somehow suppressed before the observer gets it (note by the way that this is suggested by writing the model down in the Edit 3-way, the Edit 2-way suggests another possible "story", but ultimately they're equivalent indeed)? I have no idea, and you don't give any information that makes this clearer, despite numerous attempts to get this information out of you...